# Cannot access build number in Azure Devops pipeline bash script

Tags: bash, azure-devops

I have this line of code in bash script in my Azure Devops pipeline:

```sh
cat <(printf " \n") <(echo $version $env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER $current_date) <(tail -n+7 changelog-update.md) ./CHANGELOG.md > output
```

The output it prints however looks like this:

> Version: :BUILD_BUILDNUMBER Thu Oct 1 18:29:19 CEST 2020

How can I access the build number of the build in the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably an issue with how you are referencing the variable.  Take a look at the documentation on how to [access variables through the environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#access-variables-through-the-environment).

> Notice that variables are also made available to scripts through
> environment variables. The syntax for using these environment
> variables depends on the scripting language.
>
> The name is upper-cased, and the . is replaced with the _. This is
> automatically inserted into the process environment. Here are some
> examples:
>
> - Batch script: %VARIABLE_NAME%
> - PowerShell script: $env:VARIABLE_NAME
> - Bash script: $VARIABLE_NAME